# VB.Net SQL Count Statement into a label

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to count the students whose teacher where `teacher = '" & lblTeacher.Text & "'"`

EXAMPLE :

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\Dbase.mdb"
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim da, da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt, dt1 As New DataTable
Dim sql As String
Dim ds As New DataSet

Public Sub display()
    sql = "select * from Info"
    dt.Clear()
    con.Open()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
End Sub
Public Sub count()
    sql = "select COUNT(name) from Info where teacher = '" & lblTeacher.Text & "'"
    da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    ds.Clear()
    con.Open()
    da.Fill(ds)
    lblCount.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString
    con.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = conn
    display()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    lblTeacher.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("teacher").Value.ToString
    count()
End Sub
End Class
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ACXx.png):

Comment: and the problem i'm facing is ... ? the error i'm getting is ... ?

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Also: seems strange to use an old JET mdb Access file, rather than a newer ACE accdb file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your current `count()` method. Pay special attention to my comments; they address some poor practices from the original code:

```vb
' Better functional style: accept a value, return the result
Public Function GetStudentCount(teacher As String) As Integer
    '**NEVER** use string concatenation to put data into an SQL command!!!
    Const sql As String = "select COUNT(name) from Info where teacher =  ?"

    'Don't try to re-use the same connection in your app.
    '  It creates a bottleneck, and breaks ADO.Net's built-in connection pooling,
    '  meaning it's more likely to make object use *worse*, rather than better.
    'Additionally, connection objects should be created in a Using block,
    '  so they will still be closed if an exception is thrown.
    '  The original code would have left the connection hanging open.
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conn), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

        'This, rather than string concatenation, is how you should put a value into your sql command
        'Note that this NEVER directly replaces the "?" character with the parameter value,
        '   even in the database itself. The command and the data are always kept separated.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("teacher", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = teacher

        con.Open()
        '    No need to fill a whole dataset, just to get one integer back
        Return DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)

       'No need to call con.Close() manually. The Using block takes care of it for you.
    End Using
End Function
```

Here it is again, without all the extra comments:

```
Public Function GetStudentCount(teacher As String) As Integer
    Const sql As String = "select COUNT(name) from Info where teacher =  ?"

    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conn), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("teacher", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = teacher           
        con.Open()
        Return DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
    End Using
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    lblTeacher.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("teacher").Value.ToString()
    lblCount.Text = GetStudentCount(lblTeacher.Text).ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, I had a bug in the code for a while (ExecuteNonQuery() vs ExecuteScalar()). It's fixed now, so you may want to check it again.